# Many HTTPS websites show "Your connection is not private" in Chrome and IE, but open in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, browser, internet-explorer

I have **windows7 - 64 bit** and **Chrome** as browser.
Many https websites can't open in Chrome and IE but  ok in Firefox.
I see following page in Chrome:

[image]

> #### Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from ticktick.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: Is your system up to date? Your Windows CA trust store may be out of date.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome and IE shares the same certificate store (which is Windows' own cert store).

Firefox on the other hand bring their own cert store.

Somehow the certificate (or the root CA) for ticktick.com cert is not trusted by Windows cert store. Either you deleted the root CA yourself, or some windows update made it untrusted/removed.

ticktick.com certificate thumbprint/fingerprint from my browser:

```
‎a9 d1 94 ec f0 03 de be 4b a8 2c 27 90 1e e0 6d 14 e9 81 17
```

And I double checked using https://www.grc.com/fingerprints.htm and it confirms the same fingerprint.

If you can double check using your own Chrome/IE to see if you got the same fingerprint - at least it will confirm if you got the correct cert or not. (or if you have a man-in-the-middle).

Beyond that, your system is somehow not trusting the root Certificate (or the root CA, or the intermediate CA) - which are:

Comodo Secure 
|- Comodo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA